# Rails controller - handle 404 and respond with dynamic HTML error page regardless of request format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, http-status-code-404

Suppose I have the following logic in my ApplicationController:

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :handle_routing_error

def handle_routing_error(exception)
 logger.info { "handling routing error: #{exception.message}" }
 render template: 'errors/error_404', status: 404
end
```

This renders my custom (and dynamic) 404 error page for all requests in the HTML format.

However, when someone provides a URL indicating a non-HTML format, e.g.  mysite.com/missingfile.png this throws a 500 error becauses I don't have a error_404.png template:

```
Missing template errors/error_404, public_site/error_404, application/error_404 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:png], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

How can I override the request format and always show my dynamic HTML 404 page?  I want it to work like twitter: https://twitter.com/missingfile.png.

A key point is that this is a dynamic 404 page, so the usual public/404.html route does not work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Also just a heads up: I do not want to render: none with status 404 for non-HTML formats, nor do I want to return a 406 error, which are both options on some blogs I have seen that deal with this topic.

Comment: What is your Rails version? I doubt you can still catch RoutingError from `rescue_from` as RoutingError is in middleware since 3.2.x and can't be caught at ApplicationController

Comment: Billy thanks, good point. I am using Rails 3.2.12.  This rescue clause is only being used when I manually throw 404 exceptions from controllers.  I just remembered that I have a catch all mapping: match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404.

Comment: Anyways, I got the behavior that I want working. I will update my question with the solution when I have a chance.

Comment: Yes, the error can be caught at specific controller level but not ApplicationController. Here is a good ref: https://coderwall.com/p/w3ghqq

Answer (score 1):

Do this ...

```
#config/routes
get "*unmatched_route", :to => "application#error_page"


#controllers/application_controller
def error_page
  render :template => 'errors/error_404', status: 404
end
```

Comment: it is reporting every page a 404